# Laravel Backpack. Error 403 forbidden in crud lists with multiple prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

#### What I did:

*Installed "mcamara/laravel-localization"*

```
`Route::group([
'middleware' => ['web', 'role:admin', 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath'],
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale() . '/' . config('backpack.base.route_prefix'),
```

**What I expected to happen:**
*Users list*

#### What happened:

Response in network:

> URL: http://friends-here.su/en/steering-wheel/user/search
>
> Status: 403 Forbidden

#### Backpack, Laravel, PHP, DB version:

Backpack "0.9.3", Laravel "5.6", PHP "7.2"

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the `role` middleware, but remove each middleware one by one until you identify which is causing the 403 response. You can then use that information to work how to resolve it.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. It's because of localizationRedirect. This middleware set the lang. localization doesn't work without it. I'm a little disappointed. I didn't find anything to change in this middleware to make it work